# Google Alerts error "There were no results" even though many results in Search

Tags: google-alerts

It seems like [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) catches less results than an actual Google Search.

For instance, try to create a Google Alert with a search query `menuiserie thouars`:
You can see in the right panel: `There were no results for: thouars menuiserie`.
Even though [thousands](https://www.google.com/search?q=menuiserie%20thouars) [of](http://www.pagesjaunes.fr/annuaire/thouars-79/entreprises-de-menuiserie) [pages](https://sites.google.com/site/raoulmenuiserie/localisation-de-l-entreprise) have both these words. There are many results even when restricting the search to the last 24 hours.

Is there a way to receive alerts for ALL new pages that a Google Search would see?

Note:

- `Result type` is set to `Everything`
- `How many` is set to `All results`